# Suggestion on MVC 5 Razor Views on rendering partial views that contains Security objects/data

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, angularjs-directive

I have a question in my mind, I am trying to design security levels for forms like if:
1. User has only view access to the  form then only view button with related access is shown.
2. user has edit access to the form then only edit and view button with related access is shown.
For the above what I am doing is that, taking ViewBag.Rights variable value from the action and using it inside the razor view as below.

```html
//This block is _Save.cshtml
<div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="mesg">
    <br>
    <p>From Insdie The template {{mesg}}</p>
    <br><br>{{myName}}<br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="myName"><br>
    <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="open();">Save</md-button>
    @if(ViewBag.AccessRights=="edit")
    {
        @{ Html.RenderPartial("edit"); }
    }
</div>
//End

//Controller
 public ActionResult Save()
        {
           
            ViewBag.AccessRights = "edit";
            return PartialView("_Save");
           
        }
//End
```

Then the above returns the partialView to my action and generates the related html elements. but my question is that is it the correct way of working as if one has access to the website files(whether its from inside premises or outside or a team member directly access it from the server side) then can change the razor view as they are editable and clear text in .cshtml files.
Any solution / suggestion to the please.

Comment: Any comment on this please.

Comment: What did you end up doing?